# Developing .net software using AMD processor

Tags: java, .net, hardware

are there problems if i buy an AMD Quad Core Phenom to develop my .net or java application ? 
Thanks

Comment: lol no.  <<so i can comment>>

Comment: You'd only have to make sure that all the other CPUs in your development environment machines are the same; strictly AMD or Intel. No mixing allowed! Same goes for your servers.

Comment: It's an x86-64 like Intel processors. So no problem.

Comment: @p.campbell Shouldn't the frameworks handle the differences?

Comment: @P.R. - i forgot my sarcasm tags.

Comment: @p.campbell whoosh... I better drink more coffee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This processor will work great!

Also, it sounds as if you're just getting started. [Here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx) where you can learn about how to program, and you can get a Free version of Visual C#, a program that helps you to write your own programs